# icepdf not render on linux instance in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, icepdf

I am using `icepdf` in my web project. It works fine when I run this project in eclipse and also run when I use this project war on tomcat version 8/9. But when I deploy this war in Linux instance all goes fine but pdf does not render in `JFrame`. My java version and tomcat version also same as i locally use.

Here is my code

```
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingController;
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingViewBuilder;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.*; 
public class PdfPreview {
public static void pdfPreview(InputStream stream) {

    // build a component controller
    SwingController controller = new SwingController();

    SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);

    JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

    // add interactive mouse link annotation support via callback
    controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
            new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
                    controller.getDocumentViewController()));

    JFrame applicationFrame = new JFrame();
    applicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    applicationFrame.getContentPane().add(viewerComponentPanel);

    // Now that the GUI is all in place, we can try openning a PDF
    controller.openDocument(stream, "Pdf Viewer", null);
    // show the component
    applicationFrame.pack();
    applicationFrame.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Here `stream` is coming from a source

Answer (score 1):

The Swing based viewer is designed to run as a standalone application as a thick client.  Your code is likely running OK on the server but the GUI will be loaded on the Server system and not on your system.  There may also be a headless exception when the server tries to load the Swing subsystem.

If you want to launch the Viewer application via a web server you'll need to build and deploy a Java WebStart application (JWS).  An example is here, http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icepdf/tags/icepdf-6.3.0/icepdf/examples/jws/ .  You'll need to to a bit a your own research with regards to signing the jars.

You can also use the ICEpdf library to save a PDF document's page as an image and you can then use Tomcat to serve the image to the requesting client.  There is some example code that uses JSF/ICEfaces http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icepdf/tags/icepdf-6.3.0/icepdf/examples/icefaces/ .  The core capture is done by this Servlet class, http://anonsvn.icesoft.org/repo/icepdf/tags/icepdf-6.3.0/icepdf/examples/icefaces/src/main/java/org/icepdf/examples/jsf/viewer/servlet/PdfRenderer.java